# How to return a concatenated query into a class with SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.android

I am using SQLite in an Android app I'm writing. The code concatenates two parameters into one in the query but does not return it back into the holding class

My query code looks like this

```
public List<BoyRecords> getBoyOrderedList(bool direction)
{
    string order = direction ? "LastName, Firstname" : "FirstName, LastName";
    string sql = "SELECT BoyID, FirstName || \' \' || LastName AS FullName FROM BoyRecords ORDER BY " + order;
    lock (this.dbLock)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection sqlCon = new SQLiteConnection(this.DBPath))
        {
            sqlCon.Execute(Constants.DBClauseSyncOff);
            List<BoyRecords> br = sqlCon.Query<BoyRecords>(sql);
            return br;
        }
    }
}
```

where BoyRecords is just a class

```
public class BoyRecords
{
    [PreserveProps(AllMembers=true)]
    public BoyRecords()
    {
    }

    public int BoyID
    { get; set; }

    [Ignore()]
    public Guid ReplicationID
    { get; set; }


    private string lastname;
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastname) ? string.Empty : lastname;}
        set
        {
            lastname = value.Length > 30 ? value.Substring(0, 30).ToLower() : value.ToLower();
        }
    }

    private string firstname;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname) ? string.Empty : firstname;}
        set
        {
            firstname = value.Length > 30 ? value.Substring(0, 30).ToLower() : value.ToLower();
        }
    }

    private string FullName
    { get; set; }
}
```

(this is just a subset of the class, it's actually a lot bigger).

While BoyID is returned back into the class, the FullName isn't. This is probably down to me misinterpreting the SQLite manual, but is there a way to return the concatenation into the FullName field?

Comment: You've marked `FullName` as `private` try making it `public`

Comment: Thanks - force of habit! Worked a treat :)